# What does this memory map mean when I compile my program?

Tags: c++, memory, genetic-algorithm

I use g++ to compile my programs.
I get a memory map 80% of the time I execute my program. I cannot figure out what a memory map means or how to solve it.
Here is the output:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./main: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0881fdc8 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
[0x80da7f8]
[0x80dec69]
[0x80a5441]
[0x80a546d]
[0x8059227]
[0x8058b2f]
[0x8058f41]
[0x80567ec]
[0x80c075f]
[0x8048191]
======= Memory map: ========
00149000-0014a000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
08048000-08165000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 2101716    /home/armandmaree/Desktop/Projek_Fase2 (copy)/main
08166000-08168000 rw-p 0011d000 08:02 2101716    /home/armandmaree/Desktop/Projek_Fase2 (copy)/main
08168000-08170000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
09a45000-09a67000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7600000-b7621000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7621000-b7700000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b77e2000-b77e3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
bfc35000-bfc4a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted
```

If you know how I can figure out where the problem lies or at least explain to me what a memory map means, that would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `double free or corruption`: most likely you are calling `delete` on something you shouldn't.

Comment: Or that you wrote beyond (before or after) the limits of your allocated memory.

Comment: Try compiling with -g, you might get a better stack trace

Comment: You should compile with `-g` to get debug info, and use e.g. [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to find out more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory map is telling you your process crashed.  The [Backtrace:] part tells you the stack back trace (which function called which function) when the crash happened.  The memory map is telling you what data is at what addresses in your process.

Like others suggested in comments, compile with -g and run your program under a debugger (gdb) to get better information.  Since your crash is caused by heap corruption, using the valgrind tool will help because it specializes in that type of problem.